# Redux store keeps resetting on page change

Tags: reactjs, redux

I currently have a multi-page React.js app where I'm using Redux as my global state manager. However, I noticed that the Redux store was being reset every time I switched pages on the site.

Since React apps run on the client's browser, it is my understanding that the redux store should persist between page changes. However, given that my app keeps resetting the redux store, I was hoping that someone could point what I might be doing wrong?

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route }                 from "react-router-dom";
import axios                from "axios";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchUserData } from "./redux/actions/userActions";

import dashboard from "./pages/dashboard";
import search    from "./pages/search";
import home      from "./pages/home";
import error     from "./pages/404";

// API URL
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api';


class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchUserData();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>

                    {/* landing page */}
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        component={ home }/>

                    {/* search page */}
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/search"
                        component={ search }/>

                    {/* dashboard page */}
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/dashboard"
                        component={ dashboard }/>

                    {/* error page */}
                    <Route
                        component={ error }/>

                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      fetchUserData: () => dispatch(fetchUserData())
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: What do you mean by a multi-page app? Is it one app with multiple views, or multiple instances of the react app?

Comment: Are you using a router that prevents page reloads on route changes?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer- I meant that its a web app that has multiple pages. I'll add the `App.js` file now for additional clarity

Comment: @HMR I'm using `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom`- not entirely sure if it blocks page reloads. Interestingly, `App.js` remounts every time I switch pages as well.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61176427/4647839

Comment: How do you navigate between pages? Are you using `Link` component? Looks like you navigate with page reloading (`location.replace` or just `<a href...`).

Comment: @davbuc Thanks, but I don't think I can fix my problem here by using `<Redirect />` :(
@PasVV I'm using `<a href...`

Comment: @nugget_boi show us the code where you are navigating from one page to another page. Are you using `Link` component from react-router? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: @nugget_boi the `<a>`- tags are the problem here, have you tried to use the `<Link>` component from react-router as @lavor suggested?

Comment: @nugget_boi `not entirely sure if it blocks page reloads` in the devtools there is a network tab.

Answer (score 3):

I think I managed to fix it.

I was using `<a>` tags instead of `<Link>` components to navigate between pages, causing the page to refresh and reset the state.

(Big thanks to everyone who helped me narrow this down, especially @PasVV and @lavor)